# Is there any tool to organize development notes and ideas?

Tags: organization, project-planning, knowledge-management

I have been searching for some tool to organize my development notes, ideas and features on diferente projects.

I saw diferente tools that did part or what I need but nome combines all.
I know I can do it, but dont have the time.

Right now I use different tools to manage:

- By Project
- By versions
- Features
- Note
- requests
- bugs
- etc

Basic features I whould like:

- Organized by project
- By version
- What is it ( Note, idea, feature request, bug, etc
- Import/Priority
- Deadline
- some sort of tag to catalog it
- Code-snippet, to better illustrate
- Image to better illustrate

I'd like more, these whould do for now.

Does any one know of some tool that those this, or most of it ?

Thanks

Comment: Not only. Are looking for a way to get rid of Word, Excel, several website, Paper, etc one tool, one goal.

Comment: That's what a good bug tracker should do - text notes on workitems, histories, priorities, etc... Plus the ability to attach arbitrary documents. It has state so you can check progress and also project/category/branch classification and a tpye (defect/feature request/story/etc/etc). Eg see http://blogs.developpeur.org/photos/audrey/images/48994/original.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/de/software/jira). Jira is a bugtracker, issuetracker etc... You can combine it with many add-ons (for scrum, github functionality)